# Determinant of the Antipodal Map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $f:S^n\to S^n$ be the map defined as $f(x)=-x$. (This map is called the **antipodal** map). Find the determinant of $df_p$ at a point $p\in S^n$.

The sign of determinant should not depend on the choice of point $p$ because of the symmetry of the situation. One approach (which I haven't been able to make entirely rigorous) to argue this is to consider the map $p\mapsto \det df_p$ is a continuous function. Then the connectedness of $S^n$ will show that the determinant cannot change sign.

**The gap in this continuity argument is the following**: I want to argue that the map $p\mapsto df_p$ is smooth. But this map is defined from $M$ to $??$. I am not able to see what this question mark should be filled with. Similarly. The $\det$ map should be continuous (smooth in fact). But the det map is defined on $??$ and maps to $\mathbb R$. Can somebody see what these '??' are?

In fact, the magnitude of the determinant should remain constant too though I am not able to see how to go about showing that.

One more thing which seems useful is to observe that $f\circ f=id$.
Thus $df_{-p}\ df_p=I$.

Comment: Two words for the first ??: tangent space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#The_derivative_of_a_map).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla The first $??$ is a space which contains all the objects $df_p$, where $p$ varies on $M$. I don't see how 'tangent space' is the solution to this. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: One answer is that the codomain of the map is the smooth vector bundle $f^*(TS^n) \otimes T^* S^n \cong \coprod_{p \in S^n} (T_{-p} S^n \otimes T_{p}^* S^n)$, and $p \mapsto df_p$ is a (smooth) section of this bundle.$

Comment: @Travis Thanks. This makes much more sense. Though I am not yet comfortable with vector bundles and 'tensoring' them. Can you also help me with the smoothness of $p\mapsto df_p$ in the light of the knowledge of the codomain?

Comment: @caffeinemachine You're welcome. More or less by definition there's no way to show smoothness without saying something about the smooth structure on the codomain. But you can probably show $\det df_p$ is independent of $p$ by showing that $f$ commutes with any rotation $R$ of the sphere (and using the facts that (1) the group of rotations acts transitively on the sphere, and (2) $\det R = 1$); then, you need only compute $\det df_p$ at a single point $p \in S^n$.